# Campaign Member Custom Fields

Tags: formula, custom-field, campaign, campaign-member

I need to create several campaign member custom fields for reporting purposes to measure campaign membership by acquisition **Channel** and **Medium**.

Ideally I could **create a campaign member field** for each of these dimensions, and then pull the **current values dynamically from the lead object** to load into campaign member record.

It's critical that the campaign membership field **not update** when the corresponding lead fields update.  This happens often as the attribution values sync from Marketo many times a day.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There would seem to be logical tension between your desire for pulling current values dynamically from the underlying lead but not to update the CampaignMember fields in response to Marketo updates/overwrites.

It sounds as if you want the CampaignMember field to capture historical (but not live) Lead field data that was accurate at the time of creating the CampaignMember.  If so, wouldn't a CampaignMember field update workflow timed for ON CREATE do the trick?